# Defining a map object inside a loop recur - Clojure

Tags: json, clojure, functional-programming, atom-editor

I am trying to use a loop recur that creates an empty map inside the loop. For each entry in the loop (loops through a vector of maps) it will see if there is a key in the newly created map that matches the iterated values key and if not create one.

I have created this code:

```
(def meteor-map (json/read-str (clojure.string/lower-case
(slurp "https://data.nasa.gov/resource/y77d-th95.json"))))

(defn most-falls [values]
(loop [values map count-tracker{}]
  (if (empty? values)
    (count-tracker)
    (do
      (def key (keyword (get (first values) "year")))
      (if (contains? (first values) key)
        (do
          (def count-tracker (update count-tracker key inc))
          (recur (rest values) count-tracker)
        )
        (do
          (def count-tracker (assoc count-tracker key 1))
          (recur (rest values) count-tracker)
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
)

(most-falls meteor-map)
```

However when I call this function and pass in meteor-map (which is a vector of maps) i get an error saying

> wrong number of args (0) passed to persistentarraymap

I think this could be due to how I am creating the initial count-tracker object inside the loop creation but I am unsure.

Any ideas?

Thanks

PS am aware this question is a bit vague so any questions just ask!

Comment: What's the exact error? The problem is, your code as multiple issues (using `def`, and `[values map ` in `loop`), so it's hard to pin down what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: What is `(count-tracker)` supposed to be doing? That's your error. You're trying to call the map without arguments. Once you fix that though, `values map` will give you an error since `map` is a function. I think you just meant `values values`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate count-tracker is supposed to be an empty map I create and then add/update keys to depending on the value that is currently in the loop. For example if the first value has a :year of "1996" and that doesnt already exist in count-tracker it will add that key to that map. If it existed already the value (eg :1996 1) would be incremented. hope that makes sense!

Comment: But what are you trying to do with `(count-tracker)`? Just return `count-tracker`? Then remove the parenthesis around it. Remember, if you surround something in parentheses, you're calling it as a function.

Comment: @Carcigenicate that solved my problem, thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm writing an answer, as you have a few things to be mentioned. Give me a couple minutes.

Answer (score 3):

There's multiple things here to be brought up. Your main problem though is with `(count-tracker)`. You're surrounding the map in parenthesis, which means that you want to call it as a function. You can't arbitrarily add parentheses to code like you can in other languages; it has a *very* specific meaning in Clojure. `(f)` *always* means that the function `f` is being called. Just change it to `count-tracker` to return the value.

Other things:

- *NEVER* use `def` inside of a function unless it's necessary. In this case though, it's entirely unnecessary. Every use of `def` creates globals that last for the length of the program (yes, they exist even after the function exits!). Use `let` instead:

  ```
  (let [key (keyword (get (first values) "year")))]
     ... ) ; Use key here
  ```
- `(loop [values map ...]` will cause errors as well. `map` is a function, so this throws away the argument passed in to `most-falls`, overwriting it with the `map` function. This will cause an error when you try to use `values` as a sequence, since the `map` function doesn't support `empty?` or `first`, or anything else you're trying to use it for. I think you just intended to just rebind the argument to be used in the loop. Just change it to `(loop [values values ...]`. Arguably, you shouldn't shadow arguments by creating other bindings with the same name, but that's not exceedingly important here.

There's still a couple other petty things that could be improved. By using destructuring you could skip the calls to `first` and `rest`, and using `reduce` could simplify the explicit looping using `loop`, but those would detract from the main issues. Taking into consideration what I mentioned above, I'd write your function as:

```
(defn most-falls [values]
  (loop [values values
         count-tracker {}]
    (if (empty? values)
      count-tracker
      (let [key (keyword (get (first values) "year"))]
        (recur (rest values)
               (if (contains? (first values) key)
                 (update count-tracker key inc)
                 (assoc count-tracker key 1)))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

First, there is definitely an issue in that clause:

```
(loop [values map count-tracker{}]
```

I'm not use what did you try to achieve, but please take a look.

Next, never use `def` or `defn` forms inside the code, only on the top level of a namespace.

Finally, the `loop/recur` is pretty low-level form and should be used with a strong knowledge of what you are doing. More often, it might be replaced with more user-friendly ones. The [reduce](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce) would be a good one I believe. It takes an initial value (an empty map in your case), a collection and a function of two arguments where the second one is the current collection's item and the second one either an initial value or a result of the previous function call.

Inside that function, you decide whether your map has some specific key and add it if it does not.

Short example:

```
# here are some data you've read from a file
(def items [{...} {...} {...}])

# reduce process function
(defn process
  [result item]
  (if (:some-key result) ;; here, you check the current map for a key
    result               ;; return the old map if everything is ok
    (assoc result :some-key some-data)))  ;; accumulate a new key into a map

(reduce process {} items)
```